# Understanding AddHandler and pass delegates and events

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling, delegates

I am using AddHandler to wire a function to a control's event that I dynamically create:

```
Public Delegate Sub MyEventHandlerDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Public Sub BuildControl(EventHandler as System.Delegate)

         dim objMyButton as new button

         AddHandler objMyButton.Click, EventHandler

    end Sub
```

This code is generating a run-time exception stating:

**Unable to cast object of type 'MyEventHandlerDelegate' to type 'System.EventHandler'**

**What am I not understanding about System.Delegate even though AddHandler takes as an argument of type "System.Delegate"?  What Type does "EventHandler need to be to cast to a type that AddHandler can accept?**  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that you are mixing types.  The click event requires a `System.EventHandler`. Your custom delegate, although it has the same signature as `System.EventHandler`, is not a `System.EventHandler`.

So, you need to change your method take `System.EventHandler` instead of `System.Delegate`:

```
Public Sub BuildControl(EventHandler as System.EventHandler)
     dim objMyButton as new button
     AddHandler objMyButton.Click, EventHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I figured out!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate you are passing to BuildControl is of type `MyEventHandlerDelegate`. Could you show us the signature of that delegate? It could be that the signature of your delegate does not match the signature required by the Button.Click event.

Comment: I added the delegate signature.